# capistrano: notify users about deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell, deployment, capistrano

I use capistrano v3 to deploy to an RoR production server. The app is deployed to `/[...]/apps/myapp/current` and each release the "current" dir changes. I'd like to notify all users about the change. I thought using `wall`, but I get an error `wall: cannot get tty name: Inappropriate ioctl for device`. However, the `wall` command works in an `ssh` session, so I guess it's because capistrano is not an interactive shell. My current code in `deploy.rb`:

```
task :notify_deployed do
  on roles(:app) do
    run_locally do
      execute 'wall /[...]/apps/myapp/shared/cap_msg.txt'
    end
  end
end

after "deploy:finished", :notify_deployed
```